# Typescript is Type for object property

Tags: typescript

Is it possible?

```
const isNotValidated = <T>(req: NextApiRequest, res, schema: any): req.body is T => {}
```

NextApiRequest cannot be changed:

```
declare type NextApiRequest = IncomingMessage & {
    /**
     * Object of `query` values from url
     */
    query: {
        [key: string]: string | string[];
    };
    /**
     * Object of `cookies` from header
     */
    cookies: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    body: any;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're no type guards for object properties, but you can define guard for whole object:

```
interface NextApiRequestEx<T> extends NextApiRequest {
  body: T;
}

type Bar = { bar: string };

const isNotValidated = <T>(req: NextApiRequest): req is NextApiRequestEx<T> => true;

declare const req: NextApiRequest;

if (isNotValidated<Bar>(req)) {
  req.body.bar // req.body is of type Bar here
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwPYFsCWcDmBZCBnPAQ02gF4oBvAXwG4AoO0SKAOQgA9gBBMNAJQgBHAK75gUcvGTosuAsWgAySnShQA9ACpNqtZqgB5AEYArCAnFIAZlAAGIiACcQtqADdCAG1F4oVx6hQwo6eulCa6roOzgBcKmpqANoA1hAgcXjAjhiYALoZWTlQAD5QmdlYibn0arS6WjoJ+sZmFlDWdshIyWj4rv6BABYQhAAmTmERul09+HEUYVApaQUVeas5NVB1akZIo+lQhHAg9HV0GMBOVoQI0GycPPxCPsAAouwAPAAqAHxQHCucFGvge3F4AgcmXiUD2Bzi3zODCY0AAQoRHBJKLCMRssNt6HRkHBoWg8CwkMAAGpeNCjQhXUZYn6-AAUjiEcTBT0hrwAlHEOYIoGTWICeS8xB8WRJ-llRITxghPBjoMToUKueKIZLMoS0DZWWSKdTafTGZ90Y42UK+XyYUKAHRwkDOjEadRQJ0ukW+DooqBWqDDDl0Kh0IA)