# Typescript IS for async

Tags: typescript

How to?

[Without async example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488284/typescript-is-type-for-object-property/59490032#59490032).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=3#code/PTAEGMEMDtoewC6gEYFMIAsYHNUBMAoPVcAG0gCd0EBPAB3QDlUAPBAQToEsAlVARwCuqAM5IAvKADeBUHNBDUFGgC5ps%20ZoDaAa1SrQYil2jYAumqMnsoAD6GEx01rMBuDXIC%207zeDhwdLlE1GU1tPQMrUwsHJ2wfeW8PFDg8AxgadySCEwQlADNIcCZWDm4%20RTEAURYAHgAVAD5QUtRoPBFQZjZOXgFhMXU5ZFSDeqyCAloGUAAhSlBJKRRKS0drUGy-aEGuEQA1SFIuPEXQSBEaaHBQBsaACip%20NW6yvsqEAEo1J9A9rtKvQqAwQNTui2ajmE7iIJHIVAgcB2SCeL0B5X6ogQMK4%20VA9z2h2OeFq8woDyen0%20Q1ATwAdCM0gyFgRPEA).

```
// cannot be changed
declare type NextApiRequest = {
    query: {
        [key: string]: string | string[];
    };
    cookies: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    body: any;
};

interface NextApiRequestEx<T> extends NextApiRequest {
  body: T;
}

type Bar = { bar: string };

const isValid = async <T>(req: NextApiRequest): req is NextApiRequestEx<T> => true;

declare const req: NextApiRequest;

if (isValid<Bar>(req)) {
  req.body.bar 
}
```

error:

> The return type of an async function or method must be the global
>   Promise type.

Comment: The error message explains what the problem is.  Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: You've typed your function as a boolean-returning typeguard. Async functions must return a `Promise<...>` in typescript because they are actually guaranteed to do so regardless of what code you put in the function.

Comment: emm, and how can i do it with promise?

Comment: I don't believe async typeguards are a feature of typescript. Make your typeguard synchronous and have it take in whatever async results it needs directly

Comment: @CollinD thanks, please answer not in comments so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions that are tagged `async` must be typed as returning a promise, since JS guarantees that the function *will* return a promise when invoked, regardless of its body.

This is a little bit more complex because you are using a typeguard, which cannot be async. One strategy to deal with this is to make your typeguard synchronous and have it take in pre-awaited results that it might otherwise await.

As an example

```
// what we'd like to do, obviously a contrived example
async isSomething(t: Something | OtherThing): t is Something {
  const result = await someCall(t); // some async result we need to determine what t is
  return result.isSomething;
}
```

This could be changed up to

```
async isSomethingAsyncPart(t: Something | OtherThing): IsSomethingAsyncResultSet {
  // do some await'ing here
  return asyncResults; 
}
isSomethingGuard(t: Something | OtherThing, asyncResults: IsSomethingAsyncResultSet): t is Something {
  // some synchronous evaluation using t and/or asyncResults
}

// kinda yucky but :shrug_emoji:
if (isSomethingGuard(t, await isSomethingAsyncPart(t)) { . . .}
```

Not sure this is the best way to handle stuff (typeguards requiringg async work seems a little suspect overall, honestly). You may be trying to shoehorn the type system into doing something it isn't designed for.

If your typeguard really is just `() => true`, you could just make it not `async` as well.